# File does not exist from gallery intent issue?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting an image from gallery using ACTION_PICK intent :-

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 112);
```

and in onActivityResult(), i am getting the image by `getData()` which returns me the uri :- `/external/images/media/6097`

Now when i am setting this uri in an imageview by `setImageUri()` method of imageview, the image is showing, but when i am creating a file object to upload this image on server by :-

```
File imageFile = new File(uri);
```

It is saying that file does not exists. `imageFile.exists()` is returning false.

I don't know where is the issue. I have tried this on genymotion and on device but the result is the same.
In manifest, i have given permissions :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes because first thing is that your URL is not quit right, it should be with the file extension.
May i know in which API level this problem does ?

Comment: Try to get absolute path from uri.

Comment: Yes Exactly do the same as @HareshChhelana said.
kem che haresh bhai ?

Comment: Please connect the mobile to system and check the image size. Image size may be 0 bytes so error throwing file not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get absolute path from uri and create file instance using absolute path instead uri :

```
 public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            String id = "";
            if (uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":").length > 1)
                id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1];
            else if (uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":").length > 0)
                id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[0];
            if (id.length() > 0) {
                final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
                Uri tempUri = getUri();
                Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(tempUri, imageColumns, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id, null, null);
                if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else
                return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

             if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(picturePath)) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "SELECT_PICTURE... " + picturePath);
                   }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " File discarded...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```